# Как используя VK API отправить сообщение в беседу

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, pycharm, messenger

юМного пробовал, не получалось, мне нужно что бы после определенной проверки, если проверка верна, отправлялось определеннее сообщение в беседу вконтакте от сообщества.

Answer (score 2):

Держи

P.S. проверка - `if msg == 'привет':`

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token = "ТОКЕН") 
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)

def sender(id, text): # функция отправления
    vk_session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id' : id, 'message' : text, 'random_id' : 0}) # это просто запомнить

for event in longpoll.listen():                     
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW:       
        if event.to_me:                              
            if event.from_chat:                     

                msg = event.text.lower() # последние сообщение пользователя
                id = event.chat_id #id беседы в который был ивент 

                if msg == 'привет': 
                    sender(id, 'Приветики') # отправляем в sender(id, text) id беседы и текст
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session = vk_api.VkApi(token=your_token)

session.method('messages.send', {'chat_id': id, 'message': text, 'random_id': 0})
```

Comment: Можешь пожалуйста написать полный код с комментариями, я все еще плохо в этом разбираюсь, буду невероятно благодарен!)